# My anime code is not working in Visual Studio Code even though I have the library

Tags: javascript, css, anime.js

I am trying to animate my school webpage with a revealing animation, but things aren't working out how it should be,  like me trying to invoke in the anime.js library, I downloaded the file into my workspace, but it still isn't working out how it should be, here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/anime.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="text-animation">
        Welcome to our School Enterprising Group website!
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: green;
}

.text-animation {
    color: lightblue;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: "Passion One", sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.text-animation, .letter {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And finally the JavaScript Code

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("text-animation")[0];

//Replace each char with <span class="letter">{char} </span>

element.innerHTML = element.textContent.replace(/\S/g, '<span class="letter">$&</span>');

anime.timeline({loop: true})
.add({
    targets: ".text-animation .letter",
    scale: [3,1],
    opacity: [0,1],
    translateZ: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: (elem, index) => index*70,
})

.add({
    targets: ".text-animation",
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo"
})
```

Tried everything I could do but still not working, PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: Does the `anime.js` file exist inside of the `libs` directory? Will moving your JS script declarations after the Bootstrap dependencies help? Please consider providing a [mcve] so that we can help to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: There are no HTML elements with the `.letter` class

Comment: I was just using it as a reference class

Answer (score 0):

```
Add the scripts inside the body tag like this and see if it works. 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="text-animation">
        Welcome to our School Enterprising Group website!
    </div>

<script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/anime.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope, did that and still, nothing happened, just the same old webpage that is still as a rock

Answer (score 0):

Just delete your current HTML file and copy-paste the given code below. It will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Test-Animation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="text-animation">
        Welcome to our School Enterprising Group wesite!
    </div>

</body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js" integrity="sha512-z4OUqw38qNLpn1libAN9BsoDx6nbNFio5lA6CuTp9NlK83b89hgyCVq+N5FdBJptINztxn1Z3SaKSKUS5UP60Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```